# The stabiliser of $g.x$ is the subgroup $gGxg^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $X$ a G-set and $x \in X$. Show that for any $g\in G$, the stabiliser of $g.x$ is the subgroup $gGxg^{-1}$.

I found this question in the book A Course in Group Theory of J. Humphreys. I was trying solve, but this question no make sense for me. Look, $x \in X$ but $X$ is not necessarily subset of $G$, then no make sense say that $gGxg^{-1} \leq G$. For this make some sense $X$ must be subset of $G$, in this case $G=gGxg^{-1}$ that no have grace.

It is likely that I'm wrong, but I do not know why.

Comment: I suspect that it should read $gG_xg^{-1}$, where $G_x$ is the stabiliser of $x$ in $G$.

Comment: ¬¬ it's true!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake comes from (in my opinion) a bad notation (but it is widely used unfortunately). There are two subsets at stake when you give some $x\in X$ :

$$Gx=G.x:=\{g.x|g\in G\}\text{ which is the orbit of }x\text{ under the action of } G $$

$$\text{ and }$$

$$G_x=Stab_G(x):=\{g\in G|g.x=x\}\text{ the stabilizer of } x\text{ under the action of } G$$

Hence we see that $Gx$ is a subset of $X$ whereas $G_x$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Here you have mistaken $G_x$ for $Gx$. I suggest you use $Stab_G(x)$ instead of $G_x$ for the stabilizer so you won't do this mistake anymore.

Now for the proof that $gG_xg^{-1}=G_{g.x}$ it comes from the following equivalences :

$$h\in G_{g.x}\Leftrightarrow hg.x=g.x\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}hg.x=x\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}hg\in G_x\Leftrightarrow h\in gG_xg^{-1}  $$

Comment: The confusion happened exactly because of notation I always use $Stab_{G}(x)$ for denote the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$, the change for $G_{x}$ confused me.
Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin I didn't understand this last part, can you explain to me how this is implied  $g^{-1}hg\in G_x\Leftrightarrow h\in gG_xg^{-1}  $

Comment: @LeylaAlkan, it is probably just a problem of notation. Here is how I would be more explicit.  Saying that $g^{-1}hg\in G_x$ is equivalent to $\exists \gamma\in G_x$ such that $g^{-1}hg=\gamma$, this is  equivalent to  $\exists \gamma\in G_x$ such that $h=g\gamma g^{-1}$ and by the very definition of $gG_xg^{-1}$ this is equivalent to $h\in gG_xg^{-1}$.