# Show that for any $g\in G$, the stabiliser of $g.x$ is the subgroup $gG_xg^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

> Let $X$ be a G-set and $x \in X$. Show that for any $g\in G$, the stabiliser of $g.x$ is the subgroup $gG_xg^{-1}$

Now the proof I found on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255998/the-stabiliser-of-g-x-is-the-subgroup-ggxg-1?rq=1) is as follows:
$$h\in G_{g.x}\Leftrightarrow hg.x=g.x\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}hg.x=x\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}hg\in G_x\Leftrightarrow h\in gG_xg^{-1}  $$

However I can't follow the reasoning in this part : $$g^{-1}hg\in G_x\Leftrightarrow h\in gG_xg^{-1} $$

How does this hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operate $g$ from left side and $g^{-1}$ from right side. So there exists $k \in G_x$ such that $g^{-1}hg = k$ if and only if $h = gkg^{-1}$ which implies that $h \in gG_xg^{-1}$.

Comment: Are we allowed to do a such thing. I mean when there is a "=" I do what you suggest, but here is "$\in $ " In this case also we are allowed to do this as well I guess @shrinit

Comment: @LeylaAlkan I have edited my answer.